# How to access Assembly Information in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

How do you access the Assembly Information in Asp.Net (Title, Description, Company, etc.)?
Do you have to use reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the information in the assembly level attributes (eg. [`AssemblyCopyrightAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycopyrightattribute.aspx)) you will need to use reflection. However with a little helper it is quite easy:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Assembly asm) where T : Attribute {
  if (asm == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("asm"); }
  var attrs = asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
  if (attrs.Length != 1) {
    throw new ApplicationException(
      String.Format("Found {0} instances of {1} in {2}. Expected 1",
        attrs.Length, typeof(T).Name, asm.FullName));
  }
  return (T)(attrs[0]);
}
```

and thus given a type, `TargetType`, from that assembly:

```
string copyright = typeof(TargetType).Assembly.GetAttribute<AssemblyCopyrightAttribute>().Copyright;
```

Comment: This worked just fine. thank you. Is this a common procedure for web applications or do some developers put this info in the web.config file?

Comment: @tszoro No idea if it is common for Web Apps, but makes a self consistent version for any type of app much easier: just maintain a correct `AssemblyInfo.cs` (or, in my case, `SolutionInfo.cs` linked in each project).

Answer (score 0):

You're just talking about web.config?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="<AssemblyName>, Version=<Version>, Culture=<Culture>, PublicKeyToken=<PublicKeyToken>"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In code-behind, you might do this:

```
Imports System.Web.Configuration
...
WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionyouwant")
```

Here's an example from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx

Comment: Well actually I was talking about the Assembly Information dialog from the MyProject Application tab. It contains Title, Description, Company, Product, Copyright, Trademak, Assembly version, File version, GUID, and Neutral language. I didn't see this in the web.config file